# how do i loop through tables to get counts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have tried to use the following, but it seems that different nodes cannot be mixed:

```
WITH tables_i_want AS (
    SELECT *, table_schema||'.'||table_name as tbl FROM temp.redshift_mod_dates WHERE table_schema = 'whatever'
)
SELECT nspname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class AS c
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS ns
  ON c.relnamespace = ns.oid
INNER JOIN tables_i_want as tiw
    ON tiw.tbl = c.oid
AND relname not like 'pg_%'
```

so, then I tried a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE f_test()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  full_table_name1 VARCHAR;
    full_table_name VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  FOR full_table_name IN (SELECT table_schema||'.'||table_name as full_table_name FROM temp.redshift_mod_dates WHERE table_schema = 'whatever')
  LOOP
      EXECUTE 'SELECT INTO temp.redshift_tables_with_cnt %, COUNT(*) FROM %', full_table_name;
      RAISE INFO '%', full_table_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

seems there's an issue with the variable:

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" Where: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "f_test" near line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive the `row-count` for all the tables you could achieve it using the following query

```sql
select tab.table_schema,
       tab.table_name,
       tinf.tbl_rows as rows
from svv_tables tab
join svv_table_info tinf
          on tab.table_schema = tinf.schema
          and tab.table_name = tinf.table
where tab.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
      and tab.table_schema not in('pg_catalog','information_schema')
      and tinf.tbl_rows > 1
order by tinf.tbl_rows desc;
```

You can have the data stored into a temporary table and then move them to a persistant table or do further processing as required.

Comment: this is awesome, but im wondering if there's a way to loop through a table, and use the values as parameters

Comment: Sorry I didnt get the question loop through the table names and then make a `SELECT COUNT` using the table name as variable ?

Comment: @DataWrangler so basically lets say i have a table that has a column which holds a bunch of table names.  how could i loop through that table, and run a query where the `FROM` clause uses the table names it gets from the loop?